# Cannot read given property of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I'm calling this.getAllJobsAPI(); in the render function.

This successfully calls the getAllJobsAPI (as given below) and I'm able to retrieve job name from the JSON array of jobs.

```
getAllJobsAPI(){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');

fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/json', {headers: headers})
.then((result) => {
  // Get the result
  // If we want text, call result.text()
  return result.json();
}).then((jsonResult) => {
  // get all jobs 
  var jobs = [];

  Object.keys(jsonResult.jobs).forEach(function(key) {
    jobs.push(jsonResult.jobs[key].name);

    var job = jsonResult.jobs[key].name;
    console.log(job);

    this.getLastBuildAPI(job);   

});

//var a = 'meetup';
//this.getLastBuildAPI(a);
console.log(jsonResult);

})
}
```

But calling this.getLastBuildAPI(job); within the for each loop throws "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastBuildAPI' of undefined" error. But If I hardcode a name variable in the end of the function and call this.getLastBuildAPI(a); I could get the success response.

Could someone tell me why I'm not able to call this.getLastBuildAPI(job); within for-each of the JSON array? Note that I'm able to see job variable in console.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` inside the resolve callback is `undefined` (as it's a different context), while when it's outside the callback `this` is the object you expect. You can reference `this` var storing it first.

```
getAllJobsAPI(){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');
var self = this;

fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/json', {headers: headers})
.then((result) => {
  // Get the result
  // If we want text, call result.text()
  return result.json();
}).then((jsonResult) => {
  // get all jobs 
  var jobs = [];

  Object.keys(jsonResult.jobs).forEach(function(key) {
    jobs.push(jsonResult.jobs[key].name);

    var job = jsonResult.jobs[key].name;
    console.log(job);

    self.getLastBuildAPI(job);   

});

//var a = 'meetup';
//this.getLastBuildAPI(a);
console.log(jsonResult);

})
```

You can also apply another approaches.

### 1. Use `bind` method.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
Object.keys(jsonResult.jobs).forEach(function(key) {
    jobs.push(jsonResult.jobs[key].name);
    var job = jsonResult.jobs[key].name;
    console.log(job);
    this.getLastBuildAPI(job);   
}.bind(this));
```

### 2. Use `arrow` functions.

Until `arrow` functions, every `new` **function** defined its own `this` value.

For instance, `this` can be a new object in the case of a constructor.

```js
function Person(age){
  this.age=age;
  console.log(this);
}
let person=new Person(22);
```

Or `this` can **points** to the `base` object if the function created can be accessed like `obj.getAge()`.

```js
let obj={
  getAge:function(){
    console.log(this);
    return 22;
  }
}
console.log(obj.getAge());
```

An `arrow` function does not create its own `this`, it's just used the `this` value of the `enclosing` execution `context`. In the other hand, `arrow` function uses `this` of parent scope.

```
Object.keys(jsonResult.jobs).forEach((key) => {
jobs.push(jsonResult.jobs[key].name);
   var job = jsonResult.jobs[key].name;
   console.log(job);
   this.getLastBuildAPI(job);   
});
```

Comment: I updated the answer with more approaches in order to be more useful for other people

Answer (score 2):

You've passed a normal `function` to `forEach` which changed the context. If you want to preserve the context use an arrow function or, alternatively, you could create a new variable to keep a reference to `this`.

Using an arrow function:

```
Object.keys(jsonResult.jobs).forEach(key => {
    .....
    this.getLastBuildAPI(job); 
});
```

Keeping a reference to `this`:

```
var that = this;
Object.keys(jsonResult.jobs).forEach(function(key) {
     ....
    that.getLastBuildAPI(job); 
});
```